# Glassfish fails at start up ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, glassfish-3

after upgrade to the latest version of ubuntu 12.04. My glassfish startup script fails at boot.

Here are the relevant parts of my boot.log:

```
Error starting domain XXXYYY.
The server exited prematurely with exit code 0.
Before it died, it produced the following output:
.....
adName=Grizzly-kernel-thread(1);|doSelect IOException
java.net.BindException: No free port within range: 8181=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSSLSelectorHandler@19e2595
......
[#|2014-05-28T09:08:28.639-0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;|Shutting down v3 due to startup exception : No free port within range: 80=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSelectorHandler@197e2a6|#]
```

But, when I run the command from console **sudo service glassfish start** the service starts fine.

This is my init script:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

#!/bin/sh
#
# glassfish init script for Linux
# Simplest possible case -- no password file, one default domain
# it would be simple to add such options

GLASSFISH_HOME=${GLASSFISH_HOME:-"/home/glassfish"}

case "$1" in
start)
    $GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin start-domain XXXYYY >/dev/null
    ;;
stop)
    $GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin stop-domain XXXYYY >/dev/null
    ;;
restart)
    $GLASSFISH_HOME/bin/asadmin restart-domain XXXYYY >/dev/null
    ;;
\*)
    echo "usage: $0 (start|stop|restart|help)"
esac
```

I will thank any help

Comment: I think your `Required-Start` line is wrong and triggers a start of the fish before the network is up, something it absolutely doesn't like.  Have a look at [this script](http://www.lyonlabs.org/howto/glassfish-3.1.2.2), they use `# Required-Start:    $local_fs $remote_fs $network $syslog $named`.

Comment: Thank you. I did the change and adjust your script but i get the same error: 
[#|2014-05-28T11:34:04.311-0500|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.server|_ThreadID=1;_ThreadName=main;|Shutting down v3 due to startup exception : No free port within range: 8081=com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.monitor.MonitorableSSLSelectorHandler@d6cffa|#]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I remove the startup service with **sudo  update-rc.d -f glassfish remove** and added the execution of the script to the /etc/rc.local file.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

exit 0

/etc/init.d/glassfish start
```